# Resources for learning to create mobile GIS Apps using Windows 8 Metro?

Tags: web-mapping, mobile, references, windows-8

I have no experience with either mobile apps or Windows 8 Metro.

Are there any good resources out there that would be good for getting started from ground zero?

Comment: ArcGIS SDK Runtime? http://video.arcgis.com/watch/1140/windows-8-metro-style-applications

Comment: if you are willing to step into FOSS tools. there is a lot.!!. Is there any specific reasons to choose windows 8?